# Ajax executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written an ajax post request however it seems to be executing multiple times.  The first time I click the button it will execute only once, however the second time I click the button it will run through the code twice, three times will execute three times and so on.  I am not sure what is causing this problem, here is my ajax post request.  If any other information is needed I will happily provide.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#postEditDatasource').click(function (event) {
    //serialise and assign json data to hidden field
    $('#dsDeletedDP').val(JSON.stringify(deleted));
    $('#dsEditedDP').val(JSON.stringify(editDPArr));

    //get the form
    var form = $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm');

    var URL = 'Settings/EditDatasource';

    $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').on('submit', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {

                reloadPostEditAction($('#dsID').val());

                if (deletedDatapoints != null) {
                    DeleteFromTable(deleted);
                }

                //clear all values from hidden inputs
                $('input:hidden').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('name') != '__RequestVerificationToken' && $(this).attr('id') != 'dsID') {
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                });

                $('#dsEditedDP').val('');

                ShowDatasourcePostAlert('#successPost', 3000);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR + ', ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                ShowDatasourcePostAlert('#successPost', 3000);
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
});
})
```

Comment: don't you have many #postEditDatasource created after you clicked ?

Comment: Do you know how I can check? and if that is the case it would seem to make sense.  Do you know how I can get around it?

Comment: You are rebinding to `$('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').on('submit'...` every time the click event happens - so for each subsequent click the event handler is running the callback n number of times. Either only bind once or unbind first. `$('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').off('submit')`

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experience is expected from your code.

Every time this event happens:  `$('#postEditDatasource').click(function (event) {`

You add a new event here:  `$('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').on('submit', function () {`

So, the events compound.  Every time you click the `#postEditDatasource` element, assign a submit event handler to `#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm`

In other words, the first time you click, you have one submit event handler.  The second time you click, you have two submit event handlers.  The third time you click, you will have three submit event handlers, and so on...

You can easily fix this by removing the submit event handler first (by using `.off()`, like this `$('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').off().on('submit', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

You may use event delegation and separate your eventhandlers
http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Each time you click on your `$('#postEditDatasource')` you are assigning the event `$('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm').on('submit', function () ...`. Thus, that will be something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourParentDivOrForm')on('click','#postEditDatasource', function (event) {
        //serialise and assign json data to hidden field
        $('#dsDeletedDP').val(JSON.stringify(deleted));
        $('#dsEditedDP').val(JSON.stringify(editDPArr));
    });
    $('#yourParentDivOrForm').on('submit', '#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm', function () {
        //get the form
        var form = $('#__dsAjaxAntiForgeryForm');
        var URL = 'Settings/EditDatasource';

        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {

                reloadPostEditAction($('#dsID').val());

                if (deletedDatapoints != null) {
                    DeleteFromTable(deleted);
                }

                //clear all values from hidden inputs
                $('input:hidden').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('name') != '__RequestVerificationToken' && $(this).attr('id') != 'dsID') {
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                });

                $('#dsEditedDP').val('');

                ShowDatasourcePostAlert('#successPost', 3000);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert(jqXHR + ', ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                ShowDatasourcePostAlert('#successPost', 3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```